# Register user function PDO

Tags: php, html, forms, pdo, registration

I have registration system for my website using php however when I attempt to create an account I get the error message all fields required and the data isn't inserted into my database.

Register php file

```
<?php 
require 'core/init.php';

# if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if(empty($_POST['firstname']) || ($_POST['lastname']) || ($_POST['gender']) ||empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email'])){

        $errors[] = 'All fields are required.';

    }else{

        #validating user's input with functions that we will create next
        if (strlen($_POST['password']) <6){
            $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters';
        } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) >18){
            $errors[] = 'Your password cannot be more than 18 characters long';
        }
        if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }else if ($users->email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'That email already exists.';
        }
    }

    if(empty($errors) === true){

        $firstname  = htmlentities($_POST['firstname']);
                $lastname   = htmlentities($_POST['lastname']);
                $gender         = htmlentities($_POST['gender']);
        $password   = $_POST['password'];
        $email      = htmlentities($_POST['email']);

        $users->register($firstname, $lastname, $gender, $password, $email);// Calling the register function, which we will create soon.
        header('Location: register.php?success');
        exit();
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
  echo 'Thank you for registering. Please check your email.';
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" >
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1>Register</h1>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <h4>First Name:</h4>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" />
                        <h4>Last Name:</h4>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" />
                        <h4>Gender:</h4>
                        <select name="gender" size="1" id="gender">
                        <option value="M">Male</option>
                        <option value="F">Female</option>
                        </select>
            <h4>Password:</h4>
            <input type="password" name="password" />
            <h4>Email:</h4>
            <input type="text" name="email" />  
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>


        <?php 
        # if there are errors, they would be displayed here.
        if(empty($errors) === false){
            echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>';
        }

        ?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

init php file

```
<?php 
#starting the users session
session_start();
require 'connect/database.php';
require 'classes/users.php';
require 'classes/general.php';

$users      = new Users($db);
$general    = new General();

$errors     = array();
```

Users php file

```
<?php 
class Users{

    private $db;

    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->db = $database;
    }


public function email_exists($email) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`UserID`) FROM `users` WHERE `Email`= ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $email);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}

public function register($firstname, $lastname, $gender, $password, $email){

    $time       = time();
    $ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $email_code = sha1($firstname + $lastname + microtime());
    $password   = sha1($password);

    $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`Firstname`, `LastName`, `Email`, `Password`, `Gender`, `ip`, `time`, `Email_code`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

    $query->bindValue(1, $firstname);
        $query->bindValue(2, $lastname);
    $query->bindValue(3, $email);
    $query->bindValue(4, $password);
    $query->bindValue(5, $gender);
    $query->bindValue(6, $time);
    $query->bindValue(7, $email_code);

    try{
        $query->execute();


    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }   
}
public function activate($email, $email_code) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`UserID`) FROM `users` WHERE `Email` = ? AND `Email_code` = ? AND `confirmed` = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $email);
        $query->bindValue(2, $email_code);
        $query->bindValue(3, 0);

        try{

            $query->execute();
            $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

            if($rows == 1){

                $query_2 = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `confirmed` = ? WHERE `Email` = ?");

                $query_2->bindValue(1, 1);
                $query_2->bindValue(2, $email);             

                $query_2->execute();
                return true;

            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

        public function login($email, $password) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `Password`, `UserID` FROM `users` WHERE `Email` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $email);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $data               = $query->fetch();
        $stored_password    = $data['Password'];
        $id                 = $data['UserID'];


        if($stored_password === sha1($password)){
            return $id; 
        }else{
            return false;   
        }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function email_confirmed($email) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`UserID`) FROM `users` WHERE `Email`= ? AND `confirmed` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $email);
    $query->bindValue(2, 1);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
public function userdata($id) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `UserID`= ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $id);

    try{

        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();

    } catch(PDOException $e){

        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
public function get_users() {


    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `time` DESC");

    try{
        $query->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }


    return $query->fetchAll();
}
}
```

general php file

```
<?php 
class General{


#Check if the user is logged in.
    public function logged_in () {
        return(isset($_SESSION['UserID'])) ? true : false;
    }

    #if logged in then redirect to home.php
    public function logged_in_protect() {
        if ($this->logged_in() === true) {
            header('Location: home.php');
            exit();     
        }
    }

    #if not logged in then redirect to index.php
    public function logged_out_protect() {
        if ($this->logged_in() === false) {
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }   
    }}
```

Comment: Check the actual PDO error http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php It should show you the column that is missing, etc.

Comment: the `$_POST` variables are correct when the form is submitted

Comment: I have solved the problem I didn't put `empty` before the `$_Post' variables